# Decoding reversed mulitline string encoded in base64 format automatically

Tags: python, base64, decoding

I am trting to decode the below given reversed multi line string  encoded in base64 format.

LnNlbHBtYXhlIGVzdSBvdCBlZXJmIGxlZUYgLnNldGlzYmV3IGNpZmZhcnQgaGdpaCBubyBub2l0YXNpbGFtcm9uZWQgZm8gdHBlY25vYyBlaHQgZWJpcmNzZUQgLjQ=
ZWxpZiBlbm8gbmkgZWIgdHN1TSApaXYgICAg

```
s = 'ZWxpZiBlbm8gbmkgZWIgdHN1TSApaXYgICAg'
s = s.decode('base64', 'strict')

print s[::-1]
```

by the above method I get correct strings but I have to change the string manually.

Please help.

Comment: What's wrong with `s.decode('base64')[::-1]` exactly? That's the *only* way to decode these, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters as you can see, the OP did not do it properly, your comment should probably be an answer.

Comment: @InbarRose: You mean the (useless) addition of `'strict'`? That doesn't break the decoding. I am not certain what the OP is asking, really.

Comment: The output of your sample code looks good to me. What's the problem, exactly? Is it that you don't want to write `[::-1]` every time you decode a string? In that case, you should write a `decodeReversedMultiLineString` method and use that instead.

Comment: i have to decode the multiple encoded string that i have posted above the code, i am only able to decode one string at a time i want them to automatically be decoded without manually feeding them

Comment: Is it a multi-line string? Or is it a list of strings? Are there newlines in the string? How hard is it to do a `[l.decode('base64')[::-1] for l in s.splitlines()]`?

Comment: @Martijin Pieters : it is a multi line string. i am not able to identify the eof. and if i am putting all the strings in to a list then converting them back in to strings only the first one decodes and rest does not do anything

Comment: What does "manually feeding" mean here? As in, you are writing the strings on a piece of paper and inserting them into a slot on the front of your computer? :-) Could you post the code where you are "putting all the strings in to a list then converting them back in to strings"?

Comment: @kevin as requested i have written the code on  http://codepad.org/7KOOjnOO

Comment: @Martijin Pieters I have pasted the code at http://codepad.org/7KOOjnOO I am only getting the output of only 1 line but not of others. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OP's comment:

```
list = ['LnNlbHBtYXhlIGVzdSBvdCBlZXJmIGxlZUYgLnNldGlzYmV3IGNpZmZhcnQgaGdpaCBubyBub2l0YXNpbGFtcm9uZWQgZm8gdHBlY25vYyBlaHQgZWJpcmNzZUQgLjQ=', 'ZWxpZiBlbm8gbmkgZWIgdHN1TSApaXYgICAg', 'c25vaXRhY2lmaWNlcHMgOC1QRVAgdGVlbSB0c3VNICl2ICAgIA==', 'Ni4yIG5vaHR5UCBodGl3IGtyb3cgdHN1TSApdmkgICAg', 'c2VsdWRvbSByZWh0byB5YiBlbGJhdHJvcG1pIGViIGRsdW9ocyBzc2FsQyApaWlpICAgIA==']
s = ''.join(list)
s = s.decode('base64', 'strict')
print (s[::-1])
```

the `join` operation connects all of the strings together, but only the first string is translated. This is because, when decoding a base 64 string, everything in the string past the first one or two `=` characters is ignored. Instead of joining, iterate:

```
list = ['LnNlbHBtYXhlIGVzdSBvdCBlZXJmIGxlZUYgLnNldGlzYmV3IGNpZmZhcnQgaGdpaCBubyBub2l0YXNpbGFtcm9uZWQgZm8gdHBlY25vYyBlaHQgZWJpcmNzZUQgLjQ=', 'ZWxpZiBlbm8gbmkgZWIgdHN1TSApaXYgICAg', 'c25vaXRhY2lmaWNlcHMgOC1QRVAgdGVlbSB0c3VNICl2ICAgIA==', 'Ni4yIG5vaHR5UCBodGl3IGtyb3cgdHN1TSApdmkgICAg', 'c2VsdWRvbSByZWh0byB5YiBlbGJhdHJvcG1pIGViIGRsdW9ocyBzc2FsQyApaWlpICAgIA==']
for s in list:
    s = s.decode('base64', 'strict')
    print (s[::-1])
```

Or use a list comprehension.

```
list = ['LnNlbHBtYXhlIGVzdSBvdCBlZXJmIGxlZUYgLnNldGlzYmV3IGNpZmZhcnQgaGdpaCBubyBub2l0YXNpbGFtcm9uZWQgZm8gdHBlY25vYyBlaHQgZWJpcmNzZUQgLjQ=', 'ZWxpZiBlbm8gbmkgZWIgdHN1TSApaXYgICAg', 'c25vaXRhY2lmaWNlcHMgOC1QRVAgdGVlbSB0c3VNICl2ICAgIA==', 'Ni4yIG5vaHR5UCBodGl3IGtyb3cgdHN1TSApdmkgICAg', 'c2VsdWRvbSByZWh0byB5YiBlbGJhdHJvcG1pIGViIGRsdW9ocyBzc2FsQyApaWlpICAgIA==']
print "\n".join(s.decode('base64')[::-1] for s in list)
```

Output:

```
4. Describe the concept of denormalisation on high traffic websites. Feel free to use examples.
    vi) Must be in one file
    v) Must meet PEP-8 specifications
    iv) Must work with Python 2.6
    iii) Class should be importable by other modules
```